# PhpStorm (on Linux) + Docker (CentOS) + Xdebug

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug, centos7

No stop on break point, like Xdebug does not work or I should not set parameters correctly in the PhpStorm.

Docker Linux machine:

```
cat /etc/*release
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) 
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) 
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
```

Xdebug PHP Module:

```
grep -v ';' /etc/php.d/15-xdebug.ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.auto_trace = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = 172.17.0.1 
xdebug.remote_log = "/var/log/xdebug.log"
```

PHP version:

```
php -v
PHP 7.0.29 (cli) (built: Mar 28 2018 07:46:18) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v10.2.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by ionCube Ltd.
with Xdebug v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
```

IP Address of the host machine:

```
docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
link/ether 02:42:9d:65:e4:10 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::42:9dff:fe65:e410/64 scope link 
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Docker container run with parameters:

```
docker run --privileged -h dev.localmag2.com -e "container=docker" -e XDEBUG_CONFIG="remote_host=172.17.0.1" -d -v /srv/www/vhosts/mag-unity/httpdocs:/var/www/html/ --name magento2 magento2:mag
```

Telnet from the host machine to the local IP and port 9000

```
telnet 172.17.0.1 9000
Trying 172.17.0.1...
Connected to 172.17.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet>
```

`var_dump('Hello world!')` example:

`/var/www/html/phpinfo.php:2:string 'Hello world!' (length=12)`

`echo (extension_loaded('xdebug') ? '' : 'non '), 'exists';` output :

`exists`

When I set a break point in the phpinfo.php file (or in any other file in the Magento) which is located in the web root dir, PhpStorm (Xdebug) do not want to stop there.

Any hint here, please?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: 1) With `xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1` the value of `xdebug.remote_host` is IGNORED and auto-detected IP is used (which might be wrong). 2) *"Telnet from the host machine to the local IP and port 9000"* What do you mean "from the host machine"? From where you were connecting and where to? This test should be performed from where PHP is running (**"guest"** Docker container) to the IP where IDE is running (the **host**, if both IDE and Docker are on the same machine). 3) What xdebug log has to say about it?

Comment: 1) set `xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0`, without changes. 2) When you make a docker container usually we use EXPOSE to redirect ports from the container to the host machine. I made one EXPOSE 9000 here. 3) unfortunately xdebug log is empty :(

Comment: 2) *" I made one EXPOSE 9000 here."* WHAT? Why? You should read Xdebug docs on how Xdebug works: it's Xdebug that connects to IDE and NOT other way around. If you expose TCP 9000 on host machine .. then IDE is unable to listen on that port as it's already used by Docker.

Comment: Check other tickets for `phpstorm` + `xdebug` + `docker` tags -- you will find different solutions or links to manuals there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xdebug+phpstorm+docker

Comment: 3) *"unfortunately xdebug log is empty"* This means that Xdebug may not even see a "debug me" flag (cookie or GET/POST parameter). For now you can try with `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` so Xdebug will try to debug every single request.

Comment: The `xdebug.remote_host` should point to the IP where IDE is running (as seen from inside the container).

Comment: I have found very nice video tutorial: https://serversforhackers.com/c/getting-xdebug-working 
I following what he did there, but again does not work. I do not have idea what I should check there.
2) Yea, you are right. I removed expose in the Dockerfile, but it is same, container automatically do it.